# Align figure on 2 columns paper

Tags: floats

I want to have the figures aligned in a 2 column paper 
[image]

I want the figure 8 to be aligned with the figure 11 and the same thing with figure 9 and 12 
The latex code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figuresimulation1}
  \caption{The active power tracking }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figuresimulation2}
  %\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}
  \caption{The reactive power tracking  } 
\end{figure}
blablablablabalabal.
\begin{figure}[!hp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figuresimulation3}
  % \vspace{0.2\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip} 
  \caption{The stator currents }
\end{figure}\\
blablablablabalabal. \\
blablablablabalabal 
\\
\\
\\
\vspace{0.6\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip} 
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{figuresimulation4}
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}
  \caption{The reactive power tracking }     
\end{figure}\\
\\
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{FFTAnalysisToolResult}
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip} 
  \caption{The reactive power tracking }
\end{figure}
blablablablabalabal.`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a minimal code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You don't need to not use double backslash after every line. In fact you should remove all of them, and maybe add one or two `\newline`. Then rewrite your example as a minimal example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. As it is now it does not have much to do with the picture given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**A) If all captions fit only in one line**

Basically, is as simple as set the same height to the four images. To find the best height, take the dimensions of the wider figure, let's say  one of 320x200 pixels. As the maximum width (300 pixels)  should be `\linewidth`, then the maximum height should be  200/320 pixels = `0.625\linewidth` in the four images, and that is all.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.625\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.625\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.625\linewidth]{example-image-golden-upright}
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.625\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

**b) If captions take a variable vertical space**

An easy approach is include the image and the caption inside a `minipage` of fixed proportions. This allow align at top or at bottom the contents  with a specific width (let's say `\linewidth`  for this example) and  height (let's say also `\linewidth`). Then you need estimate the vertical space allowed for  captions (let's say that 0.3\linewidth will be enough). Therefore  we can scale height images up to `0.7\linewidth` and the width images up to `1\linewidth`  (note that now is the width of the line inside the minipage, not the line outside the minipage, although in this example have not changed) as far as possible using the `keepaspectratio` to maintain height-width proportions.

Using a `\fbox{}` around the minipage is easier understand how this help to place the figures:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][t]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.7\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\caption{A medium caption. A medium caption. A medium caption.} 
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][t]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.7\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-1x1}
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][t]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.7\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-golden-upright}
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][t]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.7\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x10}
\caption{A long caption. A long caption. A long caption.A long caption.A long caption. A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

However this waste some minipage space, but if you change `[t]` to `[b]` in minipages and  `\vfill` just after the image, you can avoid the limitation of maximum height to 0.7\linewidth when a short caption left some available space:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][b]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\vfill
\caption{A medium caption. A medium caption. A medium caption. A medium caption.}   
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][b]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[height=.9\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}\vfill
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][b]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[height=.9\linewidth]{example-image-golden-upright}
\vfill
\caption{a short caption}   
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\begin{minipage}[c][\linewidth][b]{\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.7\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x10}\vfill
\caption{A long caption. A long caption. A long caption.A long caption.A long caption. A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.A long caption.}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]